# Running Water through Air Injection Softener with no power

Tags: plumbing, well-pump, water-softener

Im in no way a plumber so forgive me if this is a silly question.  I am on a well water system with an air injection softener.  Last night, the circuit breaker its on shorted out.  Im really at a loss as to why that is, because as far as I know there's only a few outside lights (none of which are on) and the softener itself on that breaker.  I suppose its possible that the breaker itself just went bad, but Im probably going to have someone out to look at it anyway.

My question is what to do about the plumbing situation in the meantime.  The reason I discovered the breaker was tripped in the first place was that the softener was making really loud sounds, and when I went into the crawlspace to try to figure out what was going on, the lightbulb wouldn't turn on, which caused me to check the breaker.  I have since turned off the water to the house, and the noise stopped, because no water is running through.  So here is my two-part question:

Im not sure how the pressure switch for the tank works and Im worried it might be on the same circuit as the softener.  The PSI on the tank is currently at about 60 (out of a 100 PSI tank).  Is this too high?  Should I turn off my well pump until the issue is fixed?

Assuming I can leave the well on, is there any harm that will be cause by running water through the softener while it is powered off? (other than the obnoxious noise)

**Edit:**
Seems like the water pressure is stabilized at 60 PSI, so its probably a 40/60 setting which is pretty common according to the internet.  It was lower this morning since I had been using the water, so I got worried when I saw it rising.  Just the question about the softener then.